# how many bipolar cells connected to a ganglion cell?

Tags: neuroscience, vision

Is it that only one bipolar cell is connected to one ganglion cell (which (ganglion cell) is connected to only one LGN neuron cell)?

I mean if more than one bipolar cell is connected to a ganglion cell, then how can the ganglion cell be ON or OFF center? Because what if two ON center and two OFF center bipolar cells are connected to the ganglion cell? Is the ganglion cell ON center or OFF center? Thanks in advance!